# Zend Framework 3: create download link for generated file

Tags: php, phpexcel, zend-framework3

I'm writing an app that lets the user upload an Excel file. It checks the file for errors, then, if no errors are found, it uploads the contents to a database. If it does find errors, the cells containing errors are colored red, then the file is saved. I then want to create a download link to this file so the user can check where they made mistakes. 
The problem is that I am not sure how to create this link and where to store the file. I modify the file like this:

```
foreach ($badCells as $bcell) {
                $sheet->getStyle($bcell)->applyFromArray(array(
                    'fill' => array(
                        'type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF4444')
                    )
                ));
            }
```

And then save it with

```
$objWriter->save($dldir . $formData['upload']['name']);
```

$dldir is created with

```
$dldir = "/download/";
        if (file_exists($dldir)) {
            if (!is_dir($dldir)) {
                unlink($dldir);
                mkdir($dldir);
            }
        } else {
            if(!is_dir($dldir)) {
                mkdir($dldir);
            }
        }
```

Is this even the right way to do this? Can I store the files in any old folder or do they have go somewhere specific? How do I create the link to the specific file in the view for the user and make it accessible so they can download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I managed to figure it out over the weekend. Here's how I did 
it:

```
$filename = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array($dldir, $formData['upload']['name']));
$objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,$filename,__FILE__));
```

This is how I save the file, using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR so it will work correctly on both Windows and Linux.

```
 return $this->redirect()->toRoute('import', ['action' => 'reject'],['query' => ['q' => 'file', 'name' => $filename]]);
```

In the controller, I redirect the route to the correct action and pass the file name on to it via a query URL.

```
public function rejectAction()
{
    $filename = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('name', null);
    return new ViewModel(array('filename' => $filename));
}
```

There, I obtain said file name through getRequest()->getQuery() and pass it on to the viewmodel.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->filename; ?>">Right-click here and choose 'Save As' to download your file.</a>
```

And finally, this is how it shows the link in reject.phtml.
Downloading only works with right click and save as, I suspect I will have to write some sort of file handler to make ZF produce the correct headers for a normal left click download.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong .

For file upload i use this library [Gargron/fileupload](https://github.com/Gargron/fileupload)
The function bellow help to upload file to a specific folder and return full link of the file. You can save the link in DB

```
    function uploadFile ($file){
        $validator = new \FileUpload\Validator\Simple('5M');

        $pathresolver = new \FileUpload\PathResolver\Simple($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload_folder');

        $filesystem = new \FileUpload\FileSystem\Simple();

        $fileupload = new \FileUpload\FileUpload(file, $_SERVER);

        $fileupload->setPathResolver($pathresolver);
        $fileupload->setFileSystem($filesystem);
        $fileupload->addValidator($validator);
        $md5Generator = new \FileUpload\FileNameGenerator\MD5 (true);
        $fileupload->setFileNameGenerator($md5Generator);

        list($files) = $fileupload->processAll();

        foreach($files as $file){
            if ($file->completed) {
               return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload_folder/'.$file->getFileName()) ;
            }
        }
       }
```